# hpacucli is unstable - Sometimes finds controller, sometimes not

Tags: ubuntu, hp, hp-proliant, ubuntu-12.04, hp-smart-array

I try to monitor the RAID-status on my HP ProLiant DL380 G5 with hpacucli 9.20. But, it's acting rather weird. Most of the time, it will return:

```
root@SERVER:~# hpacucli ctrl all show
Error: No controllers detected.
```

But now and then it actually works as intended:

```
root@SERVER:~# hpacucli ctrl all show
Smart Array P800 in Slot 4                (sn: PXXXXXXXXX)
```

I ran a few tests, and found that it fails around 90-95% of the time when i executed the command every other second over a period of 20 minutes (600 executions).

Does anyone have a clue? What can be the cause of this weird behaviour?

Technical info:

- OS: Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS 64-bit
- Kernel: Linux xen 3.2.0-29-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP
- Smart Array FW version: 7.24
- Controller: HP Smart Array P800
- hpacucli version: 9.20.9.0

Answer (score 2):

If you're just looking to monitor RAID status, executing `hpacucli` on its own as a health-check isn't the right way. I could understand it failing, too. I can't repeat the same behavior on my RHEL and CentOS servers, though. `strace` may be your friend in this case, since the failures are easily reproduced.

You want to use the `hp-snmp-agents` and `hp-health` packages for real continuous monitoring (which provides email and SNMP alerts).

Ubuntu is a bit of a compromise with HP servers, as the value-add tools aren't as well-developed as they are for more [*Enterprise operating systems*](https://serverfault.com/questions/461271/how-should-an-it-department-choose-a-linux-distribution-technical-reasons/461332#461332).

Please see my notes at: [Disk/RAID Monitoring for HP Proliant Servers and Ubuntu 12.04](https://serverfault.com/questions/446072/disk-raid-monitoring-for-hp-proliant-servers-and-ubuntu-12-04)

It seems like you'll need some combination of the software delivered by the [**SDR repository**](http://downloads.linux.hp.com/SDR/downloads/PSP/ubuntu/) detailed at: http://communitylinux.org/node/446#comment-866

Comment: Thanks for an extensive answer! What I want to do, is to monitor if any disks is in any other state than OK (and that is working perfectly, when hpacucli works..)

I know that Ubuntu is not as well supported as RHEL, but it should work nevertheless... Any other I'll compare results from strace though.